# Why the "mariadbd --wsrep_start_position=uuid" command on webmin process used a lot memory, it is posible to make it lower or need to set some config?

Tags: config, cluster-computing, centos7, galera

After run galera cluster few days, i go check webmin side for the memory usage, and saw one command is relate with galera cluster and it used 99% memory, it there any solution to make it lower or set some config to limit it, i research about the command is use for recover but should no need t keep for all, below is my galera config setup:

```
[mysqld]
#datadir = /usr/sbin/mariadbd
#tmpdir = /mysql_tmp
performance_schema =on
max_connections = 3000
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

#Tune to the Hardware
wsrep_slave_threads=8
innodb_io_capacity=80000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 10
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=4
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

#THREAD POOL
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 4
thread_pool_size = 8
thread_pool_oversubscribe = 3

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=10G; gcache.page_size=10G;"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

my cluster spec is:

- CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz, 32 cores
- RAM 64 GB
- SSD 1 TB

I have tried to restart mariadb or clear the cache, but after few hours all the node hit used 80-99% memory again.